# Celeryd time constraint error

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celeryd

While running the status command I get the following error:-

```
Am using rabbitmq as the messaging broker
```

I am following this [blog](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#generic-init-scripts)

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd status
Error: No nodes replied within time constraint
```

How can I Debug this error?

I have also checked this question. The answer there did not help.

[django/celery - celery status: Error: No nodes replied within time constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575711/django-celery-celery-status-error-no-nodes-replied-within-time-constraint)

Edit:-

After checking the logs of celery beat I found the following error

```
celerybeat raised exception <class 'gdbm.error'>: error(13, 'Permission denied')
```

Comment: What backend are you using?

Comment: @bradley.ayers rabbitmq as the messaging broker ...

Comment: Perhaps you don't have enough free disk space and RabbitMQ is blocking messages, resulting in the timeout?

Comment: No I checked the disk space with "df - h" plenty space available.

Comment: Increase logging to see what is actually happening.

Comment: @bradley.ayers I found something can you please see it.

Comment: Perhaps use strace to see what it's doing, or increase logging level to DEBUG.

Comment: I think you've run the application as root inbetween. there is a write or execute right missign somewhere. Can you please check the access rights of all your files

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I have set error logs to Info and can't see anything. (daemon is by default on warning). When I set it to debug I get all messages from SQS and its too much. Any idea which other path might need permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is caused by celery not having write permissions for the `celerybeat-schedule` file. The docs you linked to show celery configured to use `/var/run/celerybeat-schedule` as the celery beat schedule file.

Does your process have write permissions to that file? If that directory is owned by `root` (as it should be) and your process is running as anything other than the `root` user, that could cause the permission denied errors.

Check that your permissions are correct and then try deleting that file then restarting everything.

Comment: So in the end the issue was that all the log,run and the schedule files dint have write permissions properly assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to find the problem :

```
C_FAKEFORK=1 sh -x /etc/init.d/celeryd start
```

This usually happens because there are problems in your source project(permission issues, syntax error etc.)

As mentioned in celery docs:-

> If the worker starts with “OK” but exits almost immediately afterwards
>   and there is nothing in the log file, then there is probably an error
>   but as the daemons standard outputs are already closed you’ll not be
>   able to see them anywhere. For this situation you can use the
>   C_FAKEFORK environment variable to skip the daemonization step

Good Luck

Source: [Celery Docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.
Restarting rabbitmq fixed it:

```
sudo systemctl restart rabbitmq-server
```

and the strange thing is that I needed to wait at least 100 seconds.
For me, I think there is a disk problem.